# How to directly get a Google API map based on a cell tower object

Tags: google-maps-api, geolocation

How do I pass a [cell tower object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en#cell_tower_object) to the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) or [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) to get a map for wherever the tower happens to be?

I realize that I can accomplish the task in two steps by first using the [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) and then passing the location to the Maps API, but the extra round trip seems unnecessary.